# How do I compile C++ code including Google Cloud Storage library?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cpp

I'm trying to use [Cloud Storage C++ Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-cpp)

I've installed it following [instructions](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu-1804---bionic-beaver)

When I try to compile it using g++, compilation/linking failing with the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'google::cloud::storage::v0::Client::CreateDefaultClient()'
```

Where can I find compiling/building instructions for cpp google cloud SDK.

Comment: That is general question, this is specific to building google cloud SDK.

Comment: @Biffen can you please remove that duplication annotation, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had to compile it with these flags `$(pkg-config --cflags storage_client libcurl openssl google_cloud_cpp_common libcares)`

and link it with these flags `$(pkg-config --libs storage_client libcurl openssl google_cloud_cpp_common libcares) -lcrc32c`

For some reason default installation of crc32c was not fine, so I had to clone git repository and follow installation instruction there to fix it.